# Add a variable with getter and setter to an existing class

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a program using the `TreeView`, but I need
each object of type `TreeItem` to contain a boolean called `CanEdit`
along with a setter of `setCanEdit()` and a getter of `getCanEdit()`,

**How would I add these things to `TreeItem`class?**

Comment: Is TreeItem a class defined by you or its from any library?

Comment: @Alexander Romanov  it is from the JavaFX library,  javafx.scene.control.TreeItem to be specific.

Comment: It's pretty unclear why you actually need this. Why not just put the boolean in the object that is wrapped by the tree item? Can you explain more completely what it is that you are trying to do?

Comment: @James_D I see what you meant but now my focus is on trying to get the TreeCell from a specific TreeItem to make it not editable :/

Comment: You can't get the tree cell from a specific tree item. A tree item might not even be represented in a cell (if its parent is collapsed, or if it is scrolled off the screen, for example). You should implement a custom tree cell and call `setEditable(...)` either in the (more likely) `updateItem(...)` or in the `updateTreeItem(...)` method, depending on what you actually require.

Comment: @James_D How would that even work?

Comment: Assume you have a boolean in whatever class your `TreeItem` is wrapping (obviously you can just create whatever class you need that has that); then in the `updateItem(MyClass item, boolean empty)` method you do `setEditable(item.isEditAllowed())` (or whatever you call the method to access that boolean). Is not rocket science.

Comment: @James_D Is there a way to make the TreeItem editable only if "IsLeaf()" is true? This would also work

Comment: This question is probably an [X-Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but at best it is too vague and unclear to be answerable. You need to improve the question and explain what it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @James_D Well to be honest I did not ask the literal question because I thought it would be too unique for anyone else to be helped by it

Comment: What you asked makes absolutely no sense whatsoever given your subsequent comments. You seem to indicate that the existing `isLeaf()` method is true exactly when the cell representing the item should be editable. If you added another boolean to a subclass of tree item, wouldn't it then have exactly the same value as `isLeaf()`. What would be the point in that?

Comment: @James_D Well no, because at first I thought there might be a case where `isLeaf()` is true but the item should still be not editable, but on second though I would only want the ones where `isLeaf()` is true to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend TreeItem.

```
public class EditableTreeItem<T> extends TreeItem<T>{
    private boolean canEdit;
    public void setCanEdit(boolean canEdit){this.canEdit = canEdit;}
    public boolean getCanEdit(){return this.canEdit;}
}
```

Use it like:

```
TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>("Tree Root");
root.getChildren().addAll(
    new EditableTreeItem<String>("Item 1"),
    new EditableTreeItem<String>("Item 2"),
    new EditableTreeItem<String>("Item 3")
);
```

Hopefully you can add this to the existing TreeView, but you might have to extend that too in order to properly handle your new class.

Comment: I tried an approach like that, but I get an error about how I cannot cast to it

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast as you have the correct type already. Just use EditableTreeItem in place of TreeItem. See my edit, including the generic type parameters.

Comment: You might need to cast when you retrieve items from the tree, though, e.g. `EditableTreeItem<String> selected = (EditableTreeItem<String>) tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class that extends `TreeItem` and use that instead

```
class MyTreeItem extends TreeItem {
    public setCanEdit(...) ... 
    public getCanEdit() ...
}
```

Of course you will need to create appropriate constructors and delegate to super where needed.

To use it, just make sure all your nodes are of this type, e.g. `new TreeView(new MyTreeItem(...))`

Comment: I tried an approach like that, but I get an error about how I cannot cast from TreeItem to my sub class

Comment: TreeBranch rootItem = ((TreeBranch)new TreeItem<String> ("Test"));

Comment: @NopeNope Huh? Why would you cast the result of constructing something?

Comment: @James_D The reason I want the treeview to have the boolean is so that its custom TreeCell will know weather or not to let the user edit it, so I need to be able to set this variable and if I cast it inside the TreeCell wont it just be set to the default value?

Comment: @NopeNope Doesn't the tree view's [editiable property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#editableProperty) already provide that functionality out of the box? (It sounds like you need to read up on some of the basics of inheritance and casting. Casting doesn't change the value of anything.)

Comment: @James_D No because I need this to be the different on a per item basis

Answer (score 0):

Just extend **TreeItem**.

In your **TreeView** then you can use your **OwnTreeItem** including the wanted attribute with getter and setter.

Comment: You can't extend `TreeView` to make that work: for example the `setRoot(TreeItem<T>)` and `TreeItem<T> getRoot()` methods are final.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I've changed my answer accordingly. I think other answers bring it better to the point anyway :)